# applying css class dynamically to table td not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to add css class to td which is created dynamically and this is portion of my code

```
var newTD = document.createElement("td");
```

td is created but border is not coming.
td is added into table properly when user clicks on plus button.css is not applied.

css class is

```
table.ms_grid td, table.ms_grid table td
{
padding: 3px 5px;
border: 1px #D3E4F5 solid;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

this code is part of my project

please suggest solution.

Comment: what does your html look like?

Answer (score 1):

Most table cell borders won't display unless there's something within.

The old method was to add a `&nbsp;` inside however I believe there's a CSS property to always show borders. <strike>Will edit if I find it.</strike>

There it is, [`empty-cells`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#emptycells), supported in everything (current) except IE7 and below

Comment: If i delete dynamically one td from middle and not from first and last.styles are getting rendered.